# How do you disable disk write cache on Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ssd, ubuntu-core, hdparm

Since hdparm is not available, is there another way on core?

I'm using ubuntu core devices in an IoT application where we cannot risk losing data due to loss of power. This can be done on classic ubuntu with hdparm by forcing the drive to write to the disk immediately rather than doing lazy writes via write cache. Otherwise if we lose power, cached writes are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hdparm can be snapped from classic ubuntu with the following yaml file...

Use this yaml file to generate a .snap with snapcraft. Then install it on ubuntu core with 'snap install name.snap --devmode'. Once installed hdparm can be used as it is on classic ubuntu. To disable write cache on a drive, enter a similar command 'hdparm -W0 /dev/sda' with /dev/sda being the path to your drive.

```
name: hdparm # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
version: '0.1' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: HD Parm
description:
  Hard Drive Parmaeters

grade: stable # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: devmode # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

apps:
  hdparm:
    command: /sbin/hdparm

parts:
  hdparm:
    plugin: nil
    stage-packages: [hdparm]
```

Comment: I've expanded on the answer as well as the question.